# Python: lists, mutation, recursion issue

Tags: python, list, recursion, mutation

What I'm trying to do is create a final function inbounds that consumes a list of int (values) and two integers lower and upper. It produces an integer of the total numbers in values that are less than lower and greater than upper. It also mutates values. If there is an int in values that is less than lower it will mutate that value to lower and is there is an int in values that is greater than upper it will mutate that value to upper. 
ex:  listin=[-3,82,105,86,-10,119,100,70] inbounds (listint, 0, 100) => 4, and v is mutated to [0,82,100,86,0,100,100,70].

So I have tried two things so far:

The first thing I tried is:

```
def inbounds(values, lower, upper):
    if values == []:
        return 0
    elif lower <= values[0] <= upper:
        return inbounds(values[1:], lower, upper)
    elif lower > values[0]:
        values[0] = lower
        return inbounds(values[1:], lower, upper) + 1
    else:
        values[0] = upper
        return inbounds(values[1:],lower, upper) + 1
```

This does return 4 but the problem with this is that I realized it would only mutate values[0] so then I tried my 2nd attempt to solve this by creating another function that has pos instead of 0 and I add 1 to pos each time it recurses:

```
def inbounds_from(values, lower, upper, pos):
    if pos < len(values):
        return 0
    elif lower <= values[pos] <= upper:
        return inbounds(values, lower, upper, pos+1)
    elif lower > values[pos]:
        values[pos] = lower
        return inbounds(values, lower, upper, pos+1) + 1
    else:
        values[pos] = upper
        return inbounds(values,lower, upper, pos+1) + 1    

def inbounds(values, lower, upper):
    inbounds_from(values, lower, upper, 0)
```

Issue with is is that inbounds does nothing!!? Why? I don't get 4 when I test the example and I get the original inlist without any mutations...

edit: Also I tried changing the base case of pos <= len(values) and that still doesn't work

Comment: Your passing slices of your list to each recursive call, which returns a copy of the original list. You won't see any changes in the original list. Try using iteration, the Python way of doing this, or if you must use recursion, try passing the current index and incrementing with your base case being `index == len(values)`

Comment: Sorry, didn't see you already attempted to do that. The problem likely is that you are missing return in your wrapper function. It should be mutating the original, but I am away from my computer and can't fiddle with it at the moment.

Comment: Ah. Your base case is wrong. It never goes past the if' block because it should be `if pos >= len(values)` if you want to start from index 0 and count up...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I tried this but still get the same results unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is in the first condition. `if pos < len(values)` should be `pos >= len(values)` instead.

Another approach will be to use list comprehensions:

```
count = sum(upper <= v <= lower for v in values)
values = [min(upper, max(v, lower)) for v in values]  # mutate
```

Comment: I tried the pos <= len(values) still get the same response. Thanks though I guess I'll try your different approach!

Comment: This technically does not mutate `values`. You would need `values[:] = [<comprehension]`

Answer (score 0):

There were few problems with your second attempt. Your base-case is wrong - it should be `if pos >= len(values)`. Also, you were recursing on the *wrapper* function, not the helper/inside function. Finally, you need to `return` the call to your helper function in your wrapper function. See the following:

```
In [4]: def inbounds_from(values, lower, upper, pos):
   ...:     if pos >= len(values):
   ...:         return 0
   ...:     elif lower <= values[pos] <= upper:
   ...:         return inbounds_from(values, lower, upper, pos+1)
   ...:     elif lower > values[pos]:
   ...:         values[pos] = lower
   ...:         return inbounds_from(values, lower, upper, pos+1) + 1
   ...:     else:
   ...:         values[pos] = upper
   ...:         return inbounds_from(values,lower, upper, pos+1) + 1
   ...:
   ...: def inbounds(values, lower, upper):
   ...:     return inbounds_from(values, lower, upper, 0)
   ...:

In [5]: test = [-3,82,105,86,-10,119,100,70]

In [6]: inbounds(test, 0, 100)
Out[6]: 4

In [7]: test
Out[7]: [0, 82, 100, 86, 0, 100, 100, 70]
```

However, in general, recursion is to be avoided in Python. Here is a Pythonic way borrowing Marat's clever `min(max())` trick:

```
In [8]: def in_bounds_iter(values, lower, upper):
   ...:     count = 0
   ...:     for i, val in enumerate(values):
   ...:         if not(lower <=  val <= upper):
   ...:             count += 1
   ...:             values[i] = min(upper, max(val, lower))
   ...:     return count
   ...:

In [9]: test = [-3,82,105,86,-10,119,100,70]

In [10]: in_bounds_iter(test, 0, 100)
Out[10]: 4

In [11]: test
Out[11]: [0, 82, 100, 86, 0, 100, 100, 70]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and explanations! I don't know how i missed  recursing on the wrapper function, not the helper... and adding the return on the wrapper makes a lot of sense!